# Expo react native app image not work properly on testflight ios

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, testflight

I have an app login page centered on screen. When i test on locally with expo on win server and also tested mac on a simulator it works perfectly but when i do build-ios and put it to appstore and test with testflight it is not working properly.

This code works on android also.
What am i doing wrong?

You can check full code on github with master branch : https://github.com/saricabasak/keyholder
I also share releated codes below that you can check fast

View that i run expo on locally:

[image]

on testflight:

[image]

```
app.json

{
  "expo": {
    "name": "key-holder",
    "slug": "key-holder",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/kilit_logo_logo_500x500.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/kilit_logo_logo_1000x1000.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#DAD7C5"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.coderals.keyholder",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.coderals.keyholder",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "barStyle": "light-content",
      "backgroundColor": "#334393"
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

image Code:

```
import logo from '../../assets/transparentLogo.png';


export default class KeyHolderContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    let renderLogo;
    let renderText;
    if (this.props.isLogin) {
      renderLogo = (
        <Image
          source={logo}
          style={container.logoStyle}
          resizeMode="center"
        />
      );
      renderText = (
        <Text style={container.titleStyle}>
          {translate("KeyHolderWelcome")}
        </Text>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Container style={container.containerStyle}>
        {renderLogo}
        {renderText}
        {this.props.children}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

styles:

```
export const container = StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: getStyle("container.backgroundColor")
  },
  logoStyle: {
    width: "40%",
    height: "40%",
    alignSelf: "center"
  },
  titleStyle: {
    color: getStyle("container.titleColor"),
    fontSize:20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
});
```

the image size : 500 x 500 on asset folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after long efforts, I did changed below for ios and solved.

```
 <Image
          source={logo}
          style={container.logoStyle}
          resizeMode="center"
        />
```

to

```
 <Image
          source={logo}
          style={container.logoStyle}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
```